# UserControl multiple datatemplate + templateselector

Tags: wpf, user-controls, datatemplate

I need to show data inside a usercontrol in different ways depending on a flag.

To achieve this i tried the following, but using this control in the main view shows nothing.

```
<UserControl DataContext="**self**">   
 <UserControl.Resources>       
    <DataTemplate x:Key="mouseInputTemplate">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"><Run Text="{Binding Text}" /></TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="touchInputTemplate">
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Width="{Binding ImageWidth}" Height="{Binding ImageHeight}" />
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"><Run Text="{Binding Text}" /></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <local:InputModeDataTemplateSelector x:Key="inputModeTemplateSelector"
            MouseInputModeTemplate="{StaticResource mouseInputTemplate}"
            TouchInputModeTemplate="{StaticResource touchInputTemplate}" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource inputModeTemplateSelector}" />
</UserControl>
```

What am i doing wrong?
Is there a better way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank to EdPlunkett and more research i found out it is better to 
use a `ContentPresenter` here and instead of binding on `DataContext=this` bind like this (as alsways suggested when writing a UserControl)

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                            AncestorType={x:Type yourType}}}"
```

Code:

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="touchInputTemplate">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}" Width="64" Height="64" />
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Text}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="mouseInputTemplate">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Text}" />
        </DataTemplate>

        <local:InputModeDataTemplateSelector x:Key="inputModeTemplateSelector"
                MouseInputModeTemplate="{StaticResource mouseInputTemplate}"
                TouchInputModeTemplate="{StaticResource touchInputTemplate}" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                AncestorType={x:Type yourType}}}">
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource inputModeTemplateSelector}">
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ContentPresenter idea is the correct way to do it with a DataTemplateSelector, and I should have thought of it myself.

But here's yet another way to do it, which unlike my first answer, actually solves all the problems you're having:

XAML (in practice the Style would probably be defined in a separate ResourceDictionary):

```
<Window 
    x:Class="TestApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApplication"
    xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    >
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="local:TestControl">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gainsboro" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <!-- The 0 value for the InputMode enum is Mouse, so this will be the default. -->
                <Trigger Property="InputMode" Value="Mouse">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Wheat" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TestControl}">
                                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"><Run Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" /></TextBlock>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="InputMode" Value="Touch">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSkyBlue" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:TestControl}">
                                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                        <Image 
                                            Source="{TemplateBinding ImageUri}" 
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                            Width="{TemplateBinding ImageWidth}" 
                                            Height="{TemplateBinding ImageHeight}" 
                                            />
                                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"><Run Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" /></TextBlock>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <local:TestControl
            ImageHeight="100"
            ImageWidth="100"
            Text="This is the test control"
            ImageUri="http://www.optimizeagency.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/GoogleLogo.jpg"
            />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace TestApplication
{
    class TestControl : Control
    {
        public TestControl()
        {
            //  If input mode may change at runtime, you'll need an event that fires when that 
            //  happens and updates this property. 
            //  UIUtilities.GetInputMode() is just a stub in this example. 
            InputMode = UIUtilities.GetInputMode();
        }

        #region InputMode Property
        public InputMode InputMode
        {
            get { return (InputMode)GetValue(InputModeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(InputModeProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty InputModeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("InputMode", typeof(InputMode), typeof(TestControl),
                new PropertyMetadata(InputMode.Mouse));
        #endregion InputMode Property


        #region Text Property
        public String Text
        {
            get { return (String)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(String), typeof(TestControl),
                new PropertyMetadata(null));
        #endregion Text Property

        #region ImageUri Property
        //  The TemplateBinding in the template can't coerce a string to an 
        //  ImageSource, so we have to make that happen elsewhere. 
        public ImageSource ImageUri
        {
            get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageUriProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ImageUriProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageUriProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ImageUri", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(TestControl),
                new PropertyMetadata(null));
        #endregion ImageUri Property

        #region ImageHeight Property
        public float ImageHeight
        {
            get { return (float)GetValue(ImageHeightProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ImageHeightProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageHeightProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ImageHeight", typeof(float), typeof(TestControl),
                new PropertyMetadata(float.NaN));
        #endregion ImageHeight Property

        #region ImageWidth Property
        public float ImageWidth
        {
            get { return (float)GetValue(ImageWidthProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ImageWidthProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageWidthProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ImageWidth", typeof(float), typeof(TestControl),
                new PropertyMetadata(float.NaN));
        #endregion ImageWidth Property
    }

    #region This stuff belongs in a different file
    public static class UIUtilities
    {
        public static InputMode GetInputMode()
        {
            //  Here you'd do whatever you're already doing to detect the input mode
            return InputMode.Touch;
        }
    }

    public enum InputMode
    {
        Mouse,
        Touch
    }
    #endregion This stuff belongs in a different file
}
```

Comment: If set content to {binding} i get an error that look similar to an overflow at xaml tree level. Why?

Comment: Sounds like it's recursing, maybe trying to recursively instantiate the UserControl in its own content or something (it's been a long day, I'm drawing a blank on exactly how that'll fail in this specific case). {Binding} without a property name binds to the DataContext, whatever that may be. What data type are you displaying in the template? If you have an instance of it, where does that instance live? If not, you need to create one.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time. Binding on a different object solves the recursion problem, anyway i'm not getting it to work. I need the usercontrol to have some dependency property that will be set from outside the control. I can't get how can i maintain that properties and bind on a different object to avoid recursion. Setting a color background do not show anything. Any further help appreciated.

Comment: @sam I think that's a problem I've had. Try setting the DataContext of the outermost Grid to your own usercontrol instance. E. G. name the grid "_grid" and set _grid.DataContext = this; after Initialize in your constructor. A more "correct" solution is to write the XAML as a ControlTemplate and use TemplateBindings.

Comment: @sam So no distinct ViewModel in either case. The UserControl subclass is its own ViewModel.

Comment: I will let you know. Thank you.

Comment: @sam OK, I'm fully awake now and my last suggestion isn't right for this case at all because of the template switching thing. More to come.